# SaltStack - how to watch for change in directory and get name of new file

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to SaltStack, I am trying to write a script that watches a directory and if a file is dropped in it I want to be able to take the name of that new file and do something with it. The following is an example of the work flow:

1) folder `/usr/local/tmp` is normally empty

2) watch the folder for a `xxxx.tar.gz` file to appear, it can be called `<anything>.tar.gz`

3) once it appears extract the contents to `xxxx.tar.gz` `/usr/local/test`

4) delete the `/usr/local/tmp/xxxx.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create inotify beacon config on minion to watch `/usr/local/temp`
2. Create reactor config on Salt master to listen for an inotify event on that directory
3. Create reactor sls file that will cause the minion to extract said file, then delete said file.